# Sybase TSQL: exists reports positive even if the result is null

Tags: sybase

I do not expect function `exists` to report positive (i.e. returns true so "there is trade" is printed) when there is no data between the two future dates I picked at random

```
if exists(select min(dt_txn) from SOME_TRADE where dt_txn > '1 Mar 2013' and dt_txn < '8 Mar 2013' 
begin
print 'There is trade'
end
```

If I just run the select statement alone, it will return a null.

What is the proper way to use exist in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
if exists(select 1 from SOME_TRADE where dt_txn > '1 Mar 2013' and dt_txn < '8 Mar 2013') 
begin
print 'There is trade'
end
```